# Can you give console.log global styles?

Tags: javascript, css

in a global style folder, you have

```
button { color:black; background-color:hotPink} as normal.
```

but can you do anything like this for the console?

```
console { color:red; font-size: largest; }
```

Comment: Unless you have some wrapper for the console, then no. The console output is not part of the page. You *can* supply styles to the `console.log()` call itself, at least in Chrome. https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-style-console-log-contents-in-chrome-devtools

Comment: There various packages to simplify as well, eg. [chalk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk)

Comment: Why? What's the use case?

Comment: Yes! Easily with my tiny script  https://github.com/yairEO/console-colors

Comment: I guess i can import something to use, or make something simple that you can import, but in this case it was more about makin something surprising for the other devs. a "why is all my code shiny" moment